# Using AJAX in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use AJAX to allow a user to input an ID number in order to populate another area on my page.  I want to use AJAX to accomplish this.  I haven't used AJAX that much, especially while using MVC.  My AJAX should execute when my `checkIdBtn` is clicked but every time I click it, it says "The resource cannot be found.  Requested URL: `/Events/Search`".  I can't figure out what is wrong with my URL (im guessing it can't find my controller/action method?).  My controller is my `HomeController` and the action method is `getEmpInfo`.  Below is the code for my AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#CheckIdBtn').click(function () {
        var empId = $('#empId').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/getEmpInfo',
            contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
            data: { id: empId },
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'
        })
        .success(function (result) {
            $('#EmpInfoDiv').html(result);
        })
        .error(function (xhr, status) {
            alert(status);
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what is the result when you type `http://yourserver/Home/getEmpInfo` in browser?

Comment: it finds it... tells me I have a null value for my parameter for the controller.

Comment: Is the button's click event firing? (ie does the page reload) if so you need to add 'preventDefault()`

Comment: `The resource cannot be found. Requested URL: /Events/Search`: somehow you are calling `http://yourserver/Events/Search`

Comment: I know..In my address bar is puts /Events/Search instead of /home/getEmpInfo but i am not calling events/search anywhere.

Comment: I don't think it is finding my AJAX.  If i take out AJAX, it gives me the same response when I click my button

Answer (score 2):

Few points -

1. You are posting some data to the server, so, use type: 'POST' instead of 'GET'.
2. Remove dataType and contentType.
3. Make sure the action named "getEmpInfo" receives a parameter named id.

Comment: I updated it according to your points but still the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the helpers that with come with the framework.

```
url: '@Url.Action("Home", "getEmpInfo")'
```

Also, double check `getEmpInfo` works since the MVC convention is to use camel casing, i.e., GetEmpInfo. You may need a custom route for this.

Comment: I recreated my view to be GetEmpInfo and I changed my url to what you have suggested.  Now when I click my button, it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're posting to your page again when you click. Try adding `e.preventDefault();` to your click handler (I also fixed your ajax call anomalies):

```
$('#CheckIdBtn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var empId = $('#empId').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/getEmpInfo',
        data: { id: empId },
        type: 'POST'
    })
    .success(function (result) {
        $('#EmpInfoDiv').html(result);
    })
    .error(function (xhr, status) {
        alert(status);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When I have this error I run project from index file then this error is not appear.
You can try open Index or html file then click on run button.
I think your error is ... You are mixing views and partial views make sure your views and partial views are not mixed up.